# "The nested type cannot hide an enclosing type" class - Java Processing

Tags: java, processing

I'm getting this error: `The nested type cannot hide an enclosing type`.  I have looked it up, and other people seem to be declaring their class twice, which I am not.

What's weird is if I copy and paste the code into a new processing document, it works with no error. But as I'm converting it to js i need it to work with no errors after saving and opening again.

```
MotorBike Bike1, Bike2, Bike3, Bike4, Bike5, Bike6, Bike7, Bike8, Bike9;
int Score_Bike1 = 0;
int Score_Bike2 = 0;
int Score_Bike3 = 0;
int Score_Bike4 = 0;
int Score_Bike5 = 0;
int Score_Bike6 = 0;
int Score_Bike7 = 0;
int Score_Bike8 = 0;
int Score_Bike9 = 0;
String Score_Spacing = "        ";
int GameState = 0;


class MotorBike {
float Pos_X;
int Pos_Y;
float Speed;
int Size = 30;
float WheelSize = Size / 3;
color Color;


MotorBike(int Declare_X, int Declare_Y, int Declare_Speed, color Declare_Color)                                                                                                    
{
this.Pos_X = Declare_X;
this.Pos_Y = Declare_Y;
Speed = Declare_Speed;
Color = Declare_Color;
}

void move()
{
if (GameState == 1) {
  Speed = (random(0, 50) / 10);
  Pos_X = Pos_X + Speed;
}
}

void render()
{
fill(Color);
triangle(Pos_X, Pos_Y, Pos_X + Size, Pos_Y, Pos_X + Size / 2, Pos_Y -Size /      2);
fill(255);
strokeWeight(1.5);
ellipse(Pos_X, Pos_Y, WheelSize, WheelSize);
ellipse(Pos_X + Size, Pos_Y, WheelSize, WheelSize);
}
}

void setup()
{
size(700, 600);
background(200);
SpawnBikes();
}

void draw()
{
background(200);
strokeWeight(3);
line(50, 10, 50, 590);
line(650, 10, 650, 590);
strokeWeight(1);
MoveBikes(); 
DetectWinner();
DisplayScore();
}

void MoveBikes()
{
Bike1.render();
Bike1.move();
Bike2.render();
Bike2.move();
Bike3.render();
Bike3.move();
Bike4.render();
Bike4.move();
Bike5.render();
Bike5.move();
Bike6.render();
Bike6.move();
Bike7.render();
Bike7.move();
Bike8.render();
Bike8.move();
Bike9.render();
Bike9.move();
}

void DetectWinner()
{
textSize(15);
fill(0); 
if (Bike1.Pos_X >= 620) {
noLoop(); 
text("Bike 1 Wins", 310, 10, 350, 50); 
Score_Bike1 += 1;
GameState = 2;
}
if (Bike2.Pos_X >= 620) {
noLoop(); 
text("Bike 2 Wins", 310, 10, 350, 50); 
Score_Bike2 += 1;
GameState = 2;
}
if (Bike3.Pos_X >= 620) {
noLoop(); 
text("Bike 3 Wins", 310, 10, 350, 50); 
Score_Bike3 += 1;
GameState = 2;
}
if (Bike4.Pos_X >= 620) {
noLoop(); 
text("Bike 4 Wins", 310, 10, 350, 50); 
Score_Bike4 += 1;
GameState = 2;
}
if (Bike5.Pos_X >= 620) {
noLoop(); 
text("Bike 5 Wins", 310, 10, 350, 50); 
Score_Bike5 += 1;
GameState = 2;
}
if (Bike6.Pos_X >= 620) {
noLoop(); 
text("Bike 6 Wins", 310, 10, 350, 50); 
Score_Bike6 += 1;
GameState = 2;
}
if (Bike7.Pos_X >= 620) {
noLoop(); 
text("Bike 7 Wins", 310, 10, 350, 50); 
Score_Bike7 += 1;
GameState = 2;
}
if (Bike8.Pos_X >= 620) {
noLoop(); 
text("Bike 8 Wins", 310, 10, 350, 50); 
Score_Bike8 += 1;
GameState = 2;
}
if (Bike9.Pos_X >= 620) {
noLoop(); 
text("Bike 9 Wins", 310, 10, 350, 50); 
Score_Bike9 += 1;
GameState = 2;
}
}

void DisplayScore()
{
textSize(15);
fill(0); 
text("Bike 1: " + Score_Bike1 + Score_Spacing + "Bike 2: " + Score_Bike2 +   Score_Spacing + "Bike 3: " + 
Score_Bike3 + Score_Spacing +  "Bike 4: " + Score_Bike4 + Score_Spacing +   "Bike 5: " + Score_Bike5 + Score_Spacing + 
"Bike 6: " + Score_Bike6 + Score_Spacing +  "Bike 7: " + Score_Bike7 + Score_Spacing +  "Bike 8: " + Score_Bike8 + 
Score_Spacing + "Bike 9: " + Score_Bike9, 65, 530, 635, 700);
}

void keyPressed()
{
if (keyPressed) { 
if (key == ' ') 
{
  if (GameState == 0) {
    GameState = 1;
  }
  if (GameState == 2) {
    loop();
    background(200);
    SpawnBikes();
    GameState = 0;
  }
  }
}
}

void SpawnBikes()
{
Bike1 = new MotorBike(50, 100, 2, color(255, 0, 0));
Bike2 = new MotorBike(50, 150, 2, color(0, 255, 0)); 
Bike3 = new MotorBike(50, 200, 2, color(0, 0, 255)); 
Bike4 = new MotorBike(50, 250, 2, color(255, 255, 0));
Bike5 = new MotorBike(50, 300, 2, color(0, 255, 255)); 
Bike6 = new MotorBike(50, 350, 2, color(255, 0, 255)); 
Bike7 = new MotorBike(50, 400, 2, color(100, 255, 0));
Bike8 = new MotorBike(50, 450, 2, color(0, 100, 255)); 
Bike9 = new MotorBike(50, 500, 2, color(255, 0, 100));
}
```

Comment: `MotorBike(int Declare_X, int Declare_Y, int Declare_Speed, color ` , `color` variable has no type defined here

Comment: when i declare the class. there are other errors such as when i refer to variables within that class

Comment: thats weird, i must have copied it wrong. it does on the real one let me edit it

Comment: Please conform to Java coding conventions: Type names (class,interface,enum) should start with a capital letter (e.g. `BigPicture`) and have no underscores. Method, variable and field names should start with a lowercase letter (e.g. `bigPicture`) and have no underscores, and constants should be all-caps (e.g. `BIG_PICTURE`). Also, let your IDE properly indent/format your code. Currently it's unreadable.

Comment: its indented in my ide but when i copy it on here it messes it all up. plus the name formats are just prefrence. im really not looking to better my code just to fix this error

Comment: Please, it's not so difficult to copy and paste code. Java class typically starts with `package` keyword followed by `import`s all of this is missing in your code snippet.

Comment: @Betlista This is Processing code, not exactly Java. The package and import statements are not necessary.

Comment: this isnt proper java, its processing

Comment: @Will Your code works fine for me, even if I save it, close it, and open it again. What version of Processing are you using? Have you tried a good old fashioned restart of your computer?

Comment: @Will Also, what are you naming your sketch?

Comment: Yes kevin, same for me except in the original file. its called MotorBike. do you think thats the reason?

Comment: I'm sorry then, I had no idea what processing is - now I'm going to learn something, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is caused by the fact that you're naming your sketch the same thing as a class you're using inside your sketch. Your sketch can't be named `MotorBike` if you have a `MotorBike` class inside that sketch.

Either rename your sketch, or rename your class.

Behind the scenes, this is because Processing exports your sketch as a Java class, and any classes in your sketch become inner classes of that Java class. So your sketch becomes something like this:

```
class MotorBike{
   void draw(){
      //whatever
   }

   class MotorBike{
      int x;
      //whatever
   }
}
```

This is illegal Java, which is what's causing your error. You can't have an inner class with the same name as a parent class. In other words, a nested type cannot hide an enclosing type.

This is also why it works okay when you copy it into a new sketch- Processing gives your sketch a random default name, so you don't have this name collision until you save your sketch as something else.

Comment: ill give it a go, hold on

Comment: ah thankyou kevin, i remaned it and it worked. i can now convert it to js and put it on my college eport folio thanks